# Generate table_id using id value from foreign table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this SQL script which generates test data into table onboarding_tasks :

```
INSERT into onboarding_tasks (business_name, meta_title, status, task_type)
SELECT
    'Business name ' || id AS business_name,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS meta_title,
    (ARRAY['NEW','IN_PROGRESS','COMPLETED'])[floor(random()*3)+1] AS status,
    (ARRAY['CHECK', 'TEST'])[floor(random()*3)+1] AS task_type
FROM generate_series(1,25) as g(id);
```

Into second table I use this second SQL query to generate test data:

```
INSERT into onboarding_task_item (title, task_id, onboarding_tasks)
SELECT
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS title,
    generate_series(1,50) AS task_id,
    generate_series(1,50) AS onboarding_tasks
FROM generate_series(1,50) as g(id);
```

After I execute the queries I have to manually edit column `task_id` and insert valid `id` number from `onboarding_tasks`. How the second SQL query can be modified to get all rows from table `onboarding_tasks` get `id` for each row and use this `id` into the second query to insert valid `task_id`?

Comment: Are you trying to create the series `[ (1,1) , (1,2) ... (1, 49) , (1, 50) , (2,1) , (2,2) ... (2, 49) , (2, 50) ... (50,1) , (50,2) ... (50, 49) , (50, 50) ]`

Comment: hm... I'm trying to insert a range of queries.

Answer (score 1):

The first query needn't any changes:

```
INSERT into onboarding_tasks (business_name, meta_title, status, task_type)
SELECT
    'Business name ' || id AS business_name,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS meta_title,
    (ARRAY['NEW','IN_PROGRESS','COMPLETED'])[floor(random()*3)+1] AS status,
    (ARRAY['CHECK', 'TEST'])[floor(random()*3)+1] AS task_type
FROM generate_series(1,25) as g(id);
```

In the second query select from the first table. I assume `onboarding_tasks` has auto `id` column:

```
INSERT into onboarding_task_item (title, task_id, onboarding_tasks)
SELECT
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS title,
    ot.id,
    generate_series(1,50) AS onboarding_tasks
FROM onboarding_tasks ot;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3ad1ff5751766dd02c15270191fa7956)

Comment: This is the complete SQL query?

Comment: This is how the second SQL query can be modified to get all rows from the `onboarding_tasks` table .

Comment: Can you show me the complete SQL query, please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov See the updated answer, both queries are included.